# What is the difference between using self.classvariable and class.classvariable inside methods?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, self

```
class demo():
   c_v=[]
   def __init__(self):
       demo.c_v.append('one')

class demo():
   c_v=[]
   def __init__(self):
       self.c_v.append('one')
```

Both yield same result?
What are the usecases of both?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/3797387

Comment: I think my question is different

Comment: Mine is within the class , while is explanation is outside the class

Comment: @ShashiTunga Same explanation applies to both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class variable will be available to all that creates instance from that class , just like the definition of methods within a class , while instance variable will be available to that instance only.

take this example :

```
class Example:
   class_i = [1] 
   def __init__(self):
        self.instance_i = [1]

a = Example()
b = Example()
a.class_i.append(2)
b.class_i.append(3)
a.instance_i.append(40)
b.instance_i.append(50)

print a.class_i
print b.class_i
print a.instance_i
print b.instance_i
```

will give you this output:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
[1,40]
[1,50]
```